# Background-color works on chrome and not in firefox

Tags: css, forms, bootstrap-4, background-color

I'm doing a form to my web. I'm using bootstrap 4 and CSS3 for custom it. When i tried to apply a `background-color` to my select options, it works in chrome. When i tried the same with firefox it doesn't work.

I upload my test to `codepen`. It doesn't work in codepen too

https://codepen.io/alex222en/pen/qeRwLw?editors=1100

**My code :**

```css
.custom-select {
  color: #FF9900 !important;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.custom-select option {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form action="">
    <select name="" id="" class="custom-select">
      <option value="">Seleccionar Naviera</option>
      <option value="1">ARMAS</option>
      <option value="2">FREED OLSEN</option>
      <option value="3">NAVIERA 3</option>
      <option value="4">NAVIERA 4</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

I tried to change the `custom-selector` properties with the development tools in both browser unsuccessfully.

Comment: Styling the `<option>` elements like this will not work as expected because of how the browser treats them. Unlike a `div`, the `option`'s will be styled by the browser based on the user's preferences and device used. For example, I am using Chrome and I see a dark background in your example because my browser preference is set to Dark Mode. On a mobile device you want the select options to display using the native device UI (like the scroll wheel select on an iPhone). If your really need to customize the appearance of the options maybe use a different HTML element made to look like a select.

Comment: I dont know it work with the preferences of web browser. If I want to do something like that, what can I use?

Comment: A quick google search "custom css select" or something like that ;)